# UISearchBar and UISearchDisplayController on iOS8 beta5 crash

Tags: ios8

Hi,everyone.This crash only happens on iOS8.

**Summary:**
I use UISearchBar and UISearchDisplayController in my view controller ,and when I firstly click on the search bar inputing text, it works and the search bar shows the result and resigns first responder. But when I click on the search bar again,the app crash.

**Steps to Reproduce:**
1.click on the UISearchBar
2.input text
3.show search result
4.click on the UISearchBar again
5.crash

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes. My App crashing like yours. Did you found any solution for this?

Comment: I do some hack in UISearchBar and I change the delegate of searchBar's textField to some object.Originally, the "_searchController" method of system will call to delegate of searchBar's textField, but now, it will call to my object and then crash. I hope it helps.

Comment: @ylovesy Do you mean that you're setting up your own delegate for the textfield delegate on UISearchBar? Does this prevent your app from crashing? Can you explain. Thanx.

Comment: Sorry,I mean that this would cause crash.Maybe you can comment some parts of your code to find out what's going on.